# How to display some data from firebase in react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display some data from firebase, the problem is that I don't know how to do this after trying many things.

My firebase datbase looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to put this data into a calender, so I want only the date from one userID. So I can get only one date, and then use it.

How can I do this?

I now use this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref('poolog/' + userId ).on('value', (snapshot) => {
        this.setState({abc: snapshot.val().childData});

        let data = snapshot.val();
        let datums = Object.values(data);
        this.setState({datums});

    });

};
```

And then I want to render it:

```
 render(){
return(
<View>

<Text>{
this.state.datums
}</Text> 

</View>
);
}
```

Comment: What's displayed currently, and what's logged if you ```console.log(this.state.datums)``` in your render method?

Comment: Do you have the right to read the datas? Check your rules, it might forbid you to read some datas

Answer (score 1):

basically this way i put every single day of an user in an array so you can access any day.And then you can access each day by an index.

```
 componentDidMount(){
     var days = []
     firebase.database().ref('poolog/' + userId ).once('value', (snap) => {
         snap.forEach((data)=>{ 
             days.push({
                 day:data.key,
                 availableHours:data.val()
             })
          })
      console.log(days)
      //this.setState({datums:days})
      })
   }
```